# Not able to get page_story_adds_unique insight from facebook api

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am facing one issue, 
i am calling page insight api. https://graph.facebook.com/293428824150389/insights?access_token=XXX

Am able to get data but some data are not coming
like page_story_adds_unique,page_friends_of_fans, etc
(https://graph.facebook.com/293428824150389/insights/page_story_adds_unique)

I have also given read_insights,manage_pages permission to our token.
Kindly please help me out as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just investigated the same problem. Looks like this metric was removed by Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/migrations/pages-api-changes-2014-07-02